# How to return status of downloaded file to ajax call in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get status of dowmloaded file.
using ajax i'm calling download.php where logic for file download is written. if reading of file is completed then i want to return status back to ajax call,

here is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"download.php",
       type:"post",
       success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
       }
    }) 
});
```

download.php

```
<?php
    $file = "Sampletpc.xls"; 

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    $obj = readfile('uploads/'.$file);
    if ($obj !== false && !connection_aborted()) {
        unlink('uploads/'.$file);     
        $res['status'] = TRUE;
        echo json_encode($res);
    }else{
        $res['status'] = FALSE;
        echo json_encode($res);
    }


?>
```

But problem is , along with status, content of file also getting in ajax success method.

like this..

`<><>><><<<><.>.....{"status":true}..`

but i want only `{"status":true}`

Comment: Try
contentType: application/json with ajax

Comment: still it giving me same data, first content of file, then status object

Comment: I guess reseting header will solve the problem, but it is giving me error `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\Exmp1\download.php:7) in C:\wamp\www\Exmp1\download.php`

Comment: no luck...! problem remain same..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98872/discussion-between-meenakshi-and-vishal-kamal).